# Another:: How do I loop through json data with swiftyjson?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm evaluating swiftyJSON by trying something simple first and wondering what is the issue with this loop.

Here's sample data.

```
{
    "dataplot2d": [
        [0.25,2.3 ],
        [-2.5,8.09 ],
        [5.3145,20.205]
    ]
}
```

and here is code to read it into two separate arrays

```
var x:[Float] = []
var y:[Float] = []
var i:Int = 0
var t:Int = 0

var jsonArr = json["dataplot2d"].arrayValue

for ( i=0; i<jsonArr.count; i++ )//number of data points
{
    println("i \(i) t \(t) \(jsonArr[i][t])")
    x.append(jsonArr[i][0].array)
    y.append(jsonArr[i][1].array)
}
```

The error is 
`Could not find member 'array'` ??

`array` is defined https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON for `arrayValue`

```
//Non-optional [JSON]
public var arrayValue: [JSON] {
    get {
        return self.array ?? []
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Maybe this would be cleaner without swiftyJSON??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm transforming my comment into an answer so I can post code.*

In your code, `jsonArr` is your first-level array of arrays, so `jsonArr[i]` is an array of floats, and `jsonArr[i][0]` is a float, not an array. That was the source of the confusion. :)

As for the simplicity of the code, here's the same loop as yours but with a slightly "Swifter" syntax (I had to adapt the code a bit to make it work in a Playground, but it doesn't change anything to our matter):

```
var x:[Float] = []
var y:[Float] = []

let jsonArr: [[Float]] = [[0.25,2.3 ],[-2.5,8.09 ],[5.3145,20.205]]

for floatArray in jsonArr {
  x.append(floatArray[0])  // In your case, floatArray[0].float
  y.append(floatArray[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply needed to unwrap to float, too bad this isn't really documented anywhere.

```
x.append(jsonArr[i][0].array)
y.append(jsonArr[i][1].array)
```

is

```
  x.append(jsonChart[i][0].float! )
  y.append(jsonChart[i][1].float! )
```

Comment: That's because `jsonArr` is your first-level array of arrays, so `jsonArr[i]` is an array of floats, and `jsonArr[i][0]` is a float, not an array. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, much appreciated.  Initially, I thought the `.array` was needed to pull in the array then assign values while maintaining reference to values in the array.  But isn't there a simpler way to read in the array and assign it to an array without having to loop?